# Select count(*) from PL/SQL variable

Tags: variables, plsql

I am trying to wrote a PLSQL block that firstly..

grabs the table name from all_tables where rownum =1

I then want to assign this table_name to a variable.

I then want to count the number of rows of this table and print to the screen.

I have pasted my code below. Are you able to reference a variable withing a sql statement as i have?

```
DECLARE
TABLE_HOLDER VARCHAR2(200);
COUNT_OF_ROWS NUMBER;

BEGIN

SELECT TABLE_NAME INTO TABLE_HOLDER FROM ALL_TABLES 
WHERE OWNER ='ROB1' AND ROWNUM=1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLE_HOLDER);

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO COUNT_OF_ROWS FROM TABLE_HOLDER;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(COUNT_OF_ROWS);
END;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to count all rows you don't need PL/SQL for that. Consider this select:

```
    select table_name,
      to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(
                   dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) X from ROB1.'||table_name))
                      ,'/ROWSET/ROW/X')) as count
    from all_tables tables where owner = 'ROB1';
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need the [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317) function.

Answer (score 0):

There's a column called num_rows in all_tables that tell you how many rows a table has.

```
DECLARE
cursor table_rows is select table_name, num_rows from all_tables
where owner='ROB1' and NUM_ROWS>1;

t_name varchar2(100);
row_number number(30);

BEGIN

for i in table_rows loop
dbms_output.put_line('table '||i.table_name || ' has' ||i.num_rows||'   rows');
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I  would need to do this same process for views in the database as well and there is no row count attribute for views in the data dictionary.